# optional permission grant lost on chrome extension update

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

In Chrome extension, host permissions can be obtained as needed basic by using optional permissions. Are these user granted host permission was lost during extension update? Do I need to request again after extension update? From my testing, I optional host permission grants were lost during the update, even though I do not change permission settings in [the manifest](https://github.com/yathit/sugarcrm-gmail-chrome-extension/blob/master/manifest.json).

Comment: Can you be more specific? How your old and new manifests look like, and an example of you requesting optional permissions?

Comment: they dont get lost on update